# Regular expression doesn't work and another one works

Tags: regex

I need to extract sentences containing certain words for my dissertation; sentences containing the words *'establishment of'*, for instance. I wrote the following regular expression:

```
^.*\bestablishment\sof\b.*$
```

I know there exists a sentence containing these words. The only regular expression that works is `^.*\bcases\b.*$`. As the two expressions are identical in pattern, both should allow to extract sentences but only the latter does.

Comment: post the section of the text where it's supposed to work but not working.

Comment: Is this Perl? If so add it to your  tag, there a many different flavors of Regex out there.

Comment: What tool do you use? Some editor might not support every kind of regex.

Comment: `^.*` and `.*$` can be removed.

Comment: Could be a casing issue, spelling mistake, or just plain wrong string being checked - do some sanity checks

Comment: I'm using Python. The program works for sentences containing 'cases' but not for those containing 'establishment of'. I opened the file containing the corpus of sentences and it's impossible to find 'establishment of' with Ctrl + F, although there exist sentences containing 'establishment of'. I modified the regex into ^.*\bestablishment\b.*$ and it worked, however my supervisor told me it wasn't specific enough. I do need to find a solution urgently.

Comment: It matches whole lines, not sentences.

Comment: Is the diss in latex? Can there be a linebreak in front of `of`? or more than one space (try `\s+` or even `\s+\R?`)

Comment: Are you sure you have only one space between *establishment* and *of* ? I suggest you try `^.*\bestablishment\s+of\b.*$`.

Comment: There are indeed several spaces between them. This is why it didn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
^.*\bestablishment\sof\b.*$
```

But it will fail if words 'establishment' and 'of' are on different strings.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: There was `^.\bestablishment\sof\b.$`. No difference now.